# Automatically import iTunes Connect crash reports

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Apple has supported scripts to download sales data, but nothing I could find for iTunes Connect app crashes. Am I just not seeing it?

Does anyone know of a script/method to automatically download crash reports from iTunes Connect for my app?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything for this. I suggest you integrate "plcrashreporter" into your app. This gives you a lot more opportunity to get crash reports as soon as they happen.

Comment: Some stray crash reports still seem to make it to Apple's servers and not to us, so I'm curious if there is a method to get a comprehensive set of crash logs... thanks though!